# how do I create a new EKCalendar on iOS device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app where I want to schedule some events. So I want to create a new calendar for my app if it does not yet exist and if it does reference that when adding new events.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is how it is done on iOS 5 using the `EventKit` framework:

First of all you need an `EKEventStore` object to access everything:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Now you need to find the local calendar source, if you want the calendar to be stored locally. There are also sources for exchange accounts, CALDAV, MobileMe etc.:

```
// find local source
EKSource *localSource = nil;
for (EKSource *source in store.sources)
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
    {
        localSource = source;
        break;
    }
```

Now here's the part where you can fetch your previously created calendar. When the calendar is created (see below) there is an ID. This identifier has to be stored after creating the calendar so that your app can identify the calendar again. In this example I just stored the identifier in a constant:

```
NSString *identifier = @"E187D61E-D5B1-4A92-ADE0-6FC2B3AF424F";
```

Now, if you don't have an identifier yet, you need to create the calendar:

```
EKCalendar *cal;
if (identifier == nil)
{
    cal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:store];
    cal.title = @"Demo calendar";
    cal.source = localSource;
    [store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:nil];
    NSLog(@"cal id = %@", cal.calendarIdentifier);
}
```

You can also configure properties like the calendar color etc. The important part is to store the identifier for later use.
On the other hand if you already have the identifier, you can just fetch the calendar:

```
else
{
    cal = [store calendarWithIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

I put in some debug output as well:

```
NSLog(@"%@", cal);
```

Now you either way have a `EKCalendar` object for further use.

**EDIT:** As of iOS 6 `calendarWithEventStore` is depreciated, use:

```
cal = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:<#(EKEntityType)#> eventStore:<#(EKEventStore *)#>];
```

Comment: my calendar seems to sometimes appear and then disappear from my iPad Calendar App when I try and create new calendars.  I was hoping creating a new Calendar would add it to the Calendar app as well.  I need to be able to query these events and Calendar separation seems like it would be the best way to do it.

Comment: looks like it is iCloud being turned on that is deleting my events, what do I do about that?

Comment: Good question. iCloud uses a separate EKEventSource, I think of type CalDAV but definitively with a title of iCloud. Perhaps check if this source is available and if it is try to create the calendar there.

Comment: Nice code, well structure and well explained. However, there's a catch that the O.P. should be warned about: my experience is that if my app creates a local calendar, the user is unable to delete it later in the Calendar app. That seems like a bug. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any "userCanEdit"-type switch that I'm forgetting to throw...

Comment: @matt What I saw was that if a user has iCloud, if you create a local calendar it is "invisible" in iCal. But if they do not have iCloud, it shows up as expected. So I check for iCloud first, and use that if available, otherwise create it local.

Comment: What we need to mention for cal.source ?what it mean?

Comment: cal.source describes the data source from which the calendar is pulled. This may be a local calendar (on the iPhone/iPad), a CALDAV account, an exchange server etc. This code uses the local source to create a device-local calendar instead of creating a networked one.

Comment: @sairam What I'm now seeing is more disturbing: on my device, running iOS 6, code that used to work to create a local calendar and an event in that calendar now runs *without reporting any error* but does not create the calendar. This is even though I've turned off iCloud in my device.

Comment: Ooops, found out the reason, on Apple's developer forums: I had to turn off iCloud *and* disable gmail calendar synch. Until I did that, creation of a local calendar failed ***without error***.

Comment: @DennisBliefernicht for me with EKSourceTypeLocal the calendar is wasn't showed in the Calendar app, changing to EKSourceTypeSubscribed fixed that.

Comment: Good conversation. I tried but in ipad is works perfectly fine. but in my ipod custom calendar is not created. Both device have google enables. Can any one help?