# Can I add/subscribe to a calendar in EventKit?

Tags: ios, eventkit

Is it possible to add or subscribe to a whole new calendar with iPhone's EventKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, though only for iOS5 onwards

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (BOOL)saveCalendar:(EKCalendar *)calendar commit:(BOOL)commit error:(NSError **)error
```

this will save the changes you made to a calendar or will add a new calendar to the database.

detailed step by step instructions for adding a new calendar can be found here
[how do I create a new EKCalendar on iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260752/how-do-i-create-a-new-ekcalendar-on-ios-device)