# Event Kit for changing own calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

Is it possible to use EK to create events for a custom made calendar? The EK is linked to the database of the default iOS calendar and I wonder if it is possible to change that.

The framework description sais that it can be used to change the default iPhone calendar app.

Thanks

Comment: In iOS5, yes.  See this question:
[how-do-i-create-a-new-ekcalendar-on-ios-device][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260752/how-do-i-create-a-new-ekcalendar-on-ios-device