# EKCalendar doesn't appear in calendar.app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I followed this answer: [how do I create a new EKCalendar on iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260752/how-do-i-create-a-new-ekcalendar-on-ios-device)

But the calendar I create doesn't appear in the iPhones calendar.app? Should it?

Maybe I'm a bit confused? :)

The code is working and I can log the calendar etc...

Answer (score 4):

I found another approach wich is much simpler and probably more robust. 
Simply use the default calendar's source for your new calendar.

```
EKSource *theSource = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents].source;
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13991658/921573

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. The problem is that when iCloud calendars switched on, it hides the locally created ones from the calendar app. To bypass this problem the solution is to add a new calendar to iCloud source:

```
    for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources)
    {
        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"])
        {
            localSource = source;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (localSource == nil)
    {
        for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources)
        {
            if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
            {
                localSource = source;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: we're having trouble figuring out a way to tell, if after creating an iCloud Calendar, the user turns off iCloud Calendars, and returns to app. Even tho iCloud Cal is off in Settings, it still shows up in this check here as an available calendar source. any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having the same issues recently.
It appears that having iCloud calendars switched on hides the locally created ones from the calendar app.
I don't have a solution other than to switch off then off iCloud calendars.
I'll report back if I find anything else.