# Adding a new calendar programmatically to calendar app if user is using non iOS account

Tags: ios, iphone, ekeventstore

Can we add a new calendar to default calendar app programmatically if user is using any other account for calendars like yahoo or hotmail, I am getting following error:

> Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=17 "That account does not allow calendars to be added or removed."

Code works perfectly fine if user is using icould or ios calendars

Comment: Hey, have you found an answer for this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13991658/921573 worked for me, until I got users who have iCloud off and Gmail calendars on.

Comment: I ended up giving alert to users if sync fails due to this particular reason. As there seems to be no way to access outlook or mail calenders.

Comment: What I ended up doing is just using the calendar in "defaultCalendarForNewEvents"... At least users can create an event in their default calendar, if there is nothing else available.

Comment: @Siten . I did not find any solution, ended up giving alert to users if sync fails due to this particular reason

Comment: Yes, Like apple is also going with that. But I mean apple must keep their default calendar with device. It should not be hidden after adding another CalDev account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research for few days , i found that Some `EKExchange` calendars like google , yahoo does not allow us to add events in their calendars . And if that is the case than you will get error with error code 17 as follows

```
"Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=17 "That account does not allow calendars to be added or removed." "
```

There is nothing we can do about this error, So i ended up giving alert to user that "We do not have rights to access your calendar account". Hope this helps someone if they face similar issue.

Comment: Is there any way to undestend if access granded before we get such error. calendar.isImmutable == NO && calendar.allowsContentModifications == YES. And it is the same when I get such error or everything is ok.