# How to Sync Google Calendar in ios application?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, gdata

I am working on a iphone app, in which i have created a calendar and added events on it. but now i have to add these events on Google calendar. After a long search , i didn't found any good ways to do this. Please Help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721553/adding-a-new-calendar-programatically-to-calendar-app-if-user-is-using-non-ios-a/26053277#26053277 Are you facing same issue

Comment: @Bhumit No buddy. i want to sync with Google Calendar....