# Warning message in Organizer saving EKEvent

Tags: ios7, ekevent

When I create an event:

```
EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.store];

newEvent.title = title;
newEvent.startDate = startDate;
newEvent.endDate = finishDate;
newEvent.location = location;
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:hoursOffSet * 60 * 60];
[newEvent addAlarm:alarm];
newEvent.calendar = cal;


BOOL eventSaved = [self.store saveEvent:newEvent span:EKSpanFutureEvents commit:YES error:error];
NSLog(@"identifier %@",newEvent.eventIdentifier);
if (!eventSaved) {
    if(!cal)
    {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ASTEventStore" code:CALENDAR_NOT_FOUND_CODE_ERROR userInfo:NULL];
    }    
   NSLog(@"Event didn't save in calendar %@",errorSavingInCalendar);
}
```

It usually works right, but I have discovered that sometimes it's saving the event and it doesn't get any error, but I can't see the event in the calendar App, actually I can't see the calendar created neither.

When I save the event in the device I always get its id in the Organizer-> Console in this way:
: identifier /The same id than the newEvent.eventIdentifier/

Do you know what does that warning means?

////Update

Well, I noticed that when the app save the EKEvent and the warning message is shown, another message is shown too:

> : 2014-08-12 10:32:28.153|17|0x178e6d500: Region monitoring not available or enabled. Trigger ignored!

I tried too google it, but I didn't find out anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found the solution, the problem was when I was creating the calendar I was getting the source in a wrong way: (from: [how do I create a new EKCalendar on iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260752/how-do-i-create-a-new-ekcalendar-on-ios-device))

```
    // find local source for example
    EKSource *localSource = nil;
    for (EKSource *source in self.store.sources)
    {
        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)  // or another source type that supports
        {
            localSource = source;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!localSource) {
    NSLog(@"Local source is not available");
        if (error) {
              *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ASTEventStore" code:CALENDAR_ACCOUNT_NOT_TYPE_LOCAL userInfo:NULL];
        }
    }
    else{
       cal = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:self.store];
       cal.title = @"Calendar";
       cal.source = self.store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source;
       cal.CGColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

       NSError *calendarError;
       BOOL calendarSaved = [self.store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:&calendarError];
       if (!calendarSaved) {
            NSLog(@"calendar didn't saved %@",calendarError);
       }
       NSLog(@"cal id = %@", cal.calendarIdentifier);
       //We save the calendar ID
       calendarId = cal.calendarIdentifier;
       [defaults setObject:calendarId forKey:@"calendarId"];
       BOOL saved = [defaults synchronize];
       if (!saved) {
            NSLog(@"CALENDAR_ID didn't saved");
        }
   }
```

Now I getting from defaultCalendarForNewEvents:

```
    cal = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:self.store];
    cal.title = @"Calendar";
    cal.source = self.store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source;
    cal.CGColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    NSError *calendarError;
    BOOL calendarSaved = [self.store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:&calendarError];
    if (!calendarSaved) {
        NSLog(@"calendar didn't saved %@",calendarError);
    }
    NSLog(@"cal id = %@", cal.calendarIdentifier);

    if (!saved) {
        NSLog(@"CALENDAR_ID didn't saved");
    }
```

I tested and it's working great in iOS7.

I hope this help to someone :)